# Однопроходный алгоритм одной задачи

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Как решить данную задачу за один проход или не более чем за O(n)? Может быть с созданием предварительно какой-то структуры?

**Задача.** Дана последовательность натуральных чисел от 1 до N (N заранее известно) в порядке частичного "возрастания". Это означает, что число Y не может первый раз встречаться в последовательности раньше числа X, если X < Y. Каждое число встречается ровно 2 раза. Повторяющиеся числа расположены не обязательно друг за другом. Например: (1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4) или (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4) или (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1) или (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4). Разрешены операции сокращения последовательности: a) удаление двух одинаковых чисел, идущих друг за другом; b) замена двух чисел, расположенных в порядке (..., x, y, ..., у, x, ...) на одно из этих чисел, например: (..., x, y, ..., у, x, ...) -> (..., x, ..., x, ...). Определить сокращается ли последовательность до одной из трех: (), т.е. до пустой последовательности; (x, y, x, y); (x, y, z, x, y, z).

Примеры сокращений:

1. (1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2) -> (1, 2, 1, 2) применив (а) -- является (x, y, x, y);
2. (1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4) -> (2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4) применив (a) -- является (x, y, z, x, y, z);
3. (1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1) -> (1, 3, 3, 1) применив операцию (b) -> (1, 1) применив операцию (b) -> () применив операцию (a);
4. (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1) -> (1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1) применив (b) -> далее не сокращается и не является ни одной из трех;
5. (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4) не сокращается и не является ни одной из трех.

Одна из идей:

Пусть каждое число -- это скобки, открывающая и закрывающая. Причем скобки разного типа не коммутируют. Чтобы разобраться со скобочной записью за один проход, нужно сделать стек. Если на входе то же число, что наверху стека, оно убирается из стека. Если на входе большее число, чем наверху стека -- оно кладется в стек. В конце нужно всего лишь сосчитать длину оставшегося стека.

Comment: о каком порядке возрастания тут речь, если в примерах такой порядок встречается 0 раз?

Comment: Последовательность может быть любая (любой длины), удволетворяющая перечисленным в задаче условиям. Порядок "возрастания" (поэтому и в скобках) в том смысле, что числа идут 1, 2, 3, ... Не может начальная последовательность из трех чисел, быть такой например: (2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1,).

Comment: То есть, не может какое-то число B встречаться первый раз раньше числа A, если A < B.

Comment: Распишите поподробнее вторую операцию сокращения. Хотелось бы еще увидеть несколько примеров последовательностей, которые сокращаются и не сокращаются.

Comment: Подсказка: вам потребуется список и массив итераторов (в терминах c++). Запомнив в массиве место первого (последнего) вхождения заданного числа можно за O(1) проверять соседей заданного числа, в месте где оно встречается 2-й раз.

Comment: Кажется, "упорядоченность" не делает задачу проще. "Упорядочить" "неупорядоченную" последовательность можно за линейное время.

Comment: Возможно, разрешены такие удаления: `(...,x,...,y,...,у,...,x,...) -> (...,x,...,x,...)` ? Тогда упорядоченность имеет смысл.

Comment: Такие удаления: (...,x,...,y,...,у,...,x,...) -> (...,x,...,x,...) не разрешены.

Comment: По просьбе @default locale добавил в описание задачи примеры.

Comment: @Chorkov, ну допустим таким образом получится выполнить операцию (a). А как одновременно выполнить операцию (b), ведь элементы (xy ... yx) могут быть разнесены друг от друга на разное расстояние. Нам надо зафиксировать какой-то (xy), а потом пробежаться по последовательности, чтобы найти (yx). Если нашли, то удалить, чтобы было (x ... x). Но удаление, ладно, занимает O(1). Потом вернуться назад и взять (xz) и опять пробежаться по последовательности в поисках (zx). И т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Анализ

Выбор между x и y во второй операции неважен, соответственно, предположим, что всегда будет выбираться x.

Рассмотрим возможность обработки последовательности слева направо в один проход.

Допустим у нас есть последовательность `S` длины `L`, которая заканчивается числом `A` и к которой невозможно применить ни одну из операций: нет ни дубликатов, ни пар, подходящих для второй операции. Если к этой последовательности дописать справа число `B`, то получится новая последовательность длины `L+1` и возможны три варианта:

- `A` и `B` совпадают, тогда к последовательности можно применить первую операцию и получить последовательность длины `L-1`. К полученной последовательности также нельзя применить ни одну операцию, т.к. не образовалось новых пар.
- `A` не равно `B` и в `S` имеется пара `BA`, причем с другим `A`, тогда можно применить вторую операцию. В результате получится последовательность длины `L-1`, заканчивающаяся на `B`. Эту последовательность также нельзя сократить:

  - Новые дубликаты не могли образоваться. Если два числа `C` (C!=A, C!=B) не стояли рядом, то они и сейчас не стоят. `A` были вычеркнуты. `B` не могут стоять рядом, иначе `S` заканчивалась бы на `BAA` и ее можно было бы сократить.
  - Новая пара `CD` для второй операции не могла появиться, иначе `CD` и `DC` существовали бы и в S.
  - Новая пара для второй операции могли образоваться только с участием `B`. Т.к. последовательность заканчивается на `B`, то это значит что в ней есть пары `BC` и `CB`. Но тогда получаем, что в S были пары `AC` и `CA`, что невозможно.
- `A` не равно `B` и в `S` нет пары `BA`. Тогда получаем последовательность длины `L+1`, к которой нельзя применить ни одну из операций.

Вроде рассмотрел все случаи. Получается в результате дописывания к последовательности числа справа может быть выполнена максимум одна операция удаления.

### Алгоритм максимального сокращения

Нужно проходить по последовательности слева направо, обрабатывая элементы по одному:

- Если элемент совпадает с предыдущим, то удаляем оба элемента из последовательности.
- Если элемент встречается во второй раз, то находим первое вхождение элемента. Если следом за ним идет то же число что и предыдущий элемент в последовательности, то удаляем предыдущий элемент и следующий за первым.

Чтобы все это делать эффективно можно строить и обновлять массивы:

- `next` — индекс следующего неудаленного элемента в последовательности. Изначально i+1 для каждого i.
- `prev` — индекс предыдущего неудаленного элемента в последовательности. Изначально i-1 для каждого i.
- `first` — индекс первого вхождения, если элемент встречается второй раз.
- `removed` — признак удаления элемента. По нему можно построить полученную последовательность.

На такой структуре данных можно реализовать все необходимые операции.

Удаление элемента с индексом `i` из последовательности:

```
//в зависимости от реализации нужно будет добавить проверки на существование prev и next
next[prev[index]] = next[index]; 
prev[next[index]] = prev[index];
removed[index] = true;
```

Проверка на выполнение первой операции (`input` — входной массив):

```
if (input[i] == input[prev[i]]) {
```

Проверка на выполнение второй операции:

```
if (next[first[i]] < prev[i] && input[prev[i]] == input[next[first[i]]]) {
```

### Проверка результата

В результате получим максимально сокращенную последовательность, в которой больше нельзя выполнять операции. Осталось проверить удовлетворяет ли она условиям.

Если длина меньше шести, то удовлетворяет.

Если длина больше шести, то нет.

Если длина равна шести, то нужно рассмотреть случаи. Рассмотрим все последовательности из чисел `A`, `B` и `C`, в которых нет повторений (не умаляя общности считаем что первые два элемента `AB`):

```
ABACBC - не подходит
ABCABC - подходит
ABCACB - ABAB - можно сократить, такого результата не будет
ABCBAC - ACAC - можно сократить, такого результата не будет
ABCBCA - не подходит
```

Имеем всего три варианта последовательности длины шесть, которые нельзя сократить. Подходящий единственный у которого первый и четвертый элементы равны. Это условие и можно использовать для проверки.

P.S. Возможно, индексы можно каким-то хитрым образом считать на ходу и обойтись без массивов, но я такого варианта не придумал и здесь считаю что начально состояние индексов мы рассчитаем заранее. Сложность алгоритма O(n) в любом случае.
P.P.S. Идею первым озвучил [@Chorkov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186057/chorkov) в коментах. В ответе она просто подробнее расписана.
P.P.P.S. Подозрительно что мне никак не понадобилось использовать условие «частичной упорядоченности». Алгоритм сможет сокращать последовательности с произвольным порядком элементов. Главное чтобы всех было по два.

Comment: Как доказывается что ваш алгоритм сокращает строку максимально?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy По индукции. Вначале имеем пустую последовательность. На каждом шаге приписываем справа одно число, выполняем операцию (максимум одну). В результате получаем последовательность, на которой нельзя выполнить ни одну операцию. Вроде так. Надеюсь ничего не напутал.

Comment: @default locale у вас получилось превосходно объяснить. Спасибо! Но кажется, что где-то есть хитрость. Я вот не пойму про индексы. Мы заводим 2 массива. Один для элементов последовательности, другой для их индексов?

Comment: @timovadia Возможно, хитрость есть, но пока мне кажется что алгоритм должен работать. Мы заводим пять массивов. Один (`input`) для элементов последовательности. Другие четыре описаны в условии. Три для индексов, один для признаков.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если не затруднит, можете объяснить поподробнее что именно не так с `xyzyzx`

Comment: @default locale может быть сокращения можно выполнить на стеке. Тогда не понадобится пять массивов. Может быть существует какая-то минимальная структура данных или их набор?

Comment: @timovadia Возможно, но я такого варианта не придумал. Можете пока убрать галочку, вдруг кто-нибудь предложит другой вариант.

Comment: @default locale -- добавил в описание задачи не проверенную идею.

Comment: @default locale нужно ли отдельно доказывать, что алгоритм завершит работу на любой конечной длине последовательности?

Comment: @timovadia Может я что-то неправильно понял, но вроде это достаточно очевидно. Алгоритм точно выполняет конечное число операций для каждого элемента последовательности.

Comment: @default locale ну просто иногда очевидные вещи требуют доказательства или по крайней мере какого-то словесного упоминания. В случае, когда A не равно B и в S нет пары BA, не выполняется ни одна из операций. И длина L последовательности возрастает. Может быть нужно отдельно сказать, что завершение работы алгоритма следует из того, что ... Не знаю как в теоретической информатике. В математике, иногда очевидные вещи прописываются в доказательстве. Потому что одним читателям доказательства что-то может быть очевидно, а другим нет.

Comment: @timovadia Длина последовательности — 2N, конечное число. Мы выполняем конечное число операций C для каждого элемента. Т.е. в результате будет 2NC операций — конечное число. Вроде это доказательство или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: default locale думаю, что вы разбираетесь в алгоритмах лучше меня. Поэтому, не знаю. Это я чего-то не понимаю и у вас спрашиваю. Правильно я понимаю, что лучше бы в описании алгоритма привести доказательство его корректности и завершения?